# In IE11 using pseudo element ::before and display:table-cell and glyphicons contens wont show up

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

I've spent a rather good time on this now but cant come to a solution. My problem is that I want to display a glyphicon before the content of a text-block and that element with the icon has should fill up all the height that the body needs. This works in all browser versions except IE. I have boiled it down in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwaauy09/5/)

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="body">BODY</div>
</div>

.body::before {
    background: blue;
    content: "\e005";
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    display: table-cell;
    width:30%;
}

.body {
    background-color: green;
    display: table;
    width: 25%;
}
```

If you add/remove the display: table-cell on the fiddle above using IE11 you will see where my problem is. Can someone give me a solution to this, or even better, explain what is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an active [bug report](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796188/pseudo-element-display-table-cell-font-ignored) about this issue in Microsoft Connect website. On IE, `font-family` decleration is ignored in pseudo-element with `display: table-cell;` property.

To workaround this problem, you need to set `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: Or you can declare a `float` property as @Sammy mentioned. Declaring a `float` property which has a value other than `none` turns `display: table-cell` to `display: block;` (see [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo)).  So, there is no trick about the `float`, still `display` property that creates change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure floating the generated content will effectively cancel out its `display: table-cell;` property, which means its height will no longer match that of the .body element.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `float:left` to `.body` does the trick

```
.body:before {
    background: blue;
    content: "\e005";
    font-family: "Glyphicons Halflings";
    display: table-cell;
    width:30%;
    float:left;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwaauy09/12/)

---

I will keep this previous answer here. Users may find it useful:

You can try using `content: "\2665"` instead of `"/e005"`

```
.body:before {
    background: blue;
    content: "\2665";
    display: table-cell;
    width:30%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwaauy09/9/)

Click [here](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2665/index.htm) for more info.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. That work if I want a heart. I have my own font setup and the glyphicon is just an example, they are downloaded because the icon shows up if I remove the display: table.cell, Even in the fiddle.

Comment: @Sammy You're adding `float: left;` to the generated `:before` element, not the `.body` element. Unfortunately, that ties the height of the generated element to the height of its content rather than that of the .body element. I don't think that's what the OP wants.