# FontAwesome glyph not displaying in IE when using display: table-cell

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

The code below works fine in Chrome and FireFox but the glyph (a chevron) does appear for internet explorer.

Removing display:table-cell makes it appear.

I would like to keep the table-cell display in there.

Does anyone know why?

EDIT:

This only breaks on internet explorer 11 (and below) on windows 8 / 7 so maybe it is a bug?

It works on MS Edge and also IE11 on a windows 10 machine.

I've also changed the example below to show why I need table-cell.  The link needs to be indented next to the chevron like so:

[image]

```css
a {
  display: table;
  width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  padding-right: 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: '\f054';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div>
  <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```

Comment: is there an error in the developer console of IE?

Comment: Seems to be a a known bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/796188/pseudo-element-display-table-cell-font-ignored

Answer (score 1):

Alternative idea.

As its part of the table display would it be possible to have the icon behave like a table caption instead of a cell?

The icon displays on IE using the following:

```
div:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: '\f054';
    display: table-caption;
}
```

Comment: Its a great suggestion thanks.  Unfortunately table-caption doesn't line up as I want.  I have edited the post and changed the example to give more background to the intent.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like this is indeed a bug in IE11. I found some more information on another stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29379602/in-ie11-using-pseudo-element-before-and-displaytable-cell-and-glyphicons-cont. Hope this helps you find a solution.

Comment: Thanks @Tom Hood.  It did indeed set me in the right direction.  I have posted my work round.

Answer (score 0):

first of all wich version of IE are you talking about?

try adding this meta-tag to your head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

and if you're using IE8 add this script tag to your head:

```
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apologies, I should have given more info re IE version.  I've done some more testing and edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

As Tom Hood and RoToRa have kindly pointed there is a bug where pseudo element ignore the css font directives (e.g. font-family) when using table-cell.

To help anyone who this trips up I have posted my work round.

Keep the :before pseudo as display table-cell so it does the nice vertical indent and keeps the height of the real element.

Don't display anything (content: '') in the pseudo element for the child (the ).

Give it enough padding to give room to display something.

Put a pseudo element on the parent (the ).

Display the glyph using absolute positioning.

Phew!

Of course if you can get away with it and want to target latest browsers - flex box would much preferable.

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}

div::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: '\f054';
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
}

a {
  display: table;
  width: 150px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a::before {
  padding-right: 30px;
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div>
  <a href="#">i am a test link which goes over multiple lines</a>
</div>
```